# send a list from server, but how to print in the client (WCF) C#

Tags: c#, wcf, list, client, event-handling

i have a server\client (WCF) application, i need to **send a list of string from the server to the client**
 let's say the function on the server

```
List<string> RetrieveEmp (){
:
:
:

return EmpName.ToList();
}
```

**I want to show the Employees name's list in client side (win phone 7 app)**

```
    client.RetrieveEmpCompleted += new EventHandler<RetrieveEmpCompletedEventArgs>(client_RetrieveEmpCompleted)

   client. RetrieveEmpAsync();
```

I tried to do it like that

```
  void client_RetrieveEmpCompleted(object sender, RetrieveEmpCompletedEventArgs e(
        {
         // I tried to do it like that 
         //  foreach (var i in e.Result.ToList())
        // {
                listBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;//e.ResultElementAt(1)
            //}
        }
```

But it **doesn't work**, **any kind of help** I will be so thankful to you, I appreciate, if you provide any sample code.
thank you,

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String>RetrieveEmp 
{
DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
from (r in context.tablename select r.EmpName).toList();
}
```